# mypy fails to detect conditional

Tags: python, mypy, typing

A working example of the issue (Python 3.8):

```py
from typing import Union

class TestA:
    def test(self) -> str:
        return "testa"


class TestB:
    def test(self) -> str:
        return "testb"


tests = Union[TestA, TestB]
more = Union[TestA, TestB, str]


def test_pass(p: tests) -> str:
    return p.test() # No error


def test_fail(p: more) -> str:
    if type(p) in [TestA, TestB]:
        return p.test() # Item "str" of "Union[TestA, TestB, str]" has no attribute "test"
    else:
        return ""

print(test_fail(TestA()))  # "testa"
print(test_fail(TestB()))  # "testb"
print(test_fail("str"))  # "str"
```

I have this exact scenario showing up in a few places in my codebase and it's really bothering me I have to disable type checking on these lines. Is this something `mypy` is expected to miss or am I the one in error here? The error being returned seems unreasonable since a `str` could never make it to that leg of the conditional.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out `in` operator won't work here. Try testing with `is` instead:

```
def test_fail(p: more) -> str:
    if type(p) is TestA or type(p) is TestB:
        ...
```

See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html#type-narrowing-expressions for available Type Narrowing Expressions.

Comment: Huh, this becomes problematic in cases where the union is large (15 types in my case). I tried doing some trickery by looping over the types and using `is` but `mypy` didn't buy it. It seems to be looking for the exact structure of `type(p) is Type`.

Comment: Finding every possible piece of code that means "is this thing of type X" is, in general, impossible (see [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)). So mypy takes the conservative stance that it only accepts `is` and `isinstance` checks. Note that it will also understand, for instance, `type(p) is not str`, so if you only want to *exclude* one case from a union, you can do it that way. Otherwise, if you have a large union and want to exclude half of the cases and leave in the other half, I might propose that what you have is a code smell at that point.

Answer (score 2):

`mypy` cannot use the *runtime* value of an expression like `type(p) in [TestA, TestB]` to determine that `p` is not a `str`. You might use `typing.overload` instead to provide two different type signatures for type checking: one for `tests`, the other for `str`.

```
from typing import overload


@overload
def test_fail(p: tests) -> str:
    ...

@overload
def test_fail(p: str) -> str:
    ...

def test_fail(p):
    if type(p) in [TestA, TestB]:
        return p.test()
    else:
        return ""
```

(I am not sure, exactly, how `mypy` makes use of these annotations to identify the `type(p) in [TestA, TestB]` case with `tests` and the `else` with `str`. This also doesn't seem to work with `mypy --strict`, as it will complain about `test_fail` not being annotated. The lack of type hints on the actual implementation is intentional and necessary.)

Or, you can simply use `typing.cast` to tell `mypy` that you know the (more) specific type of `p`:

```
from typing import cast


def test_fail(p: more) -> str:
    if type(p) in [TestA, TestB]:
        return cast(tests, p).test() # Item "str" of "Union[TestA, TestB, str]" has no attribute "test"
    else:
        return ""
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to exclude a single case, mypy will also recognize `is not`. But it can't recognize more complex expressions like `in`.

```
if type(p) is not str:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TypeGuard like this:

```
tests = Union[TestA, TestB]

def is_tests(x) -> TypeGuard[tests]:
    return type(x) in (TestA, TestB)
```

and then:

```
if is_tests(p):
    return p.test()
```